# Existence of a Global Solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\varphi:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ be a smooth function satifying $\varphi(x)=0$ for $|x|\geq 1$ and $\varphi(x)>0$ for $|x|<1$. For example, we may define $\lambda : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ by $\lambda(t)=0$ for $t\leq 0$ and $\lambda(t)=e^{-1/t}$ for $t>0$, and then let $\varphi(x)=\lambda(1-|x|^2)$.

Fix $c\in S^{n-1}$, $x_0 \in \Bbb R^n$ and consider the differential equation $$ x'(t)= \varphi (x(t))c,~~ x(0)=x_0.$$
By a theorem in ODE, this equation has a local solution (defined near $0$). However, I heard in this special case there is in fact a global solution (defined on $\Bbb R$) (precisely, in Milnor's book, *Topology from the Differential Viewpoint*).

But I don't know well about ODEs. What condition of $\varphi$ assures that there is such a global solution?

Comment: The right hand side is globally Lipschitz.

Comment: @copper.hat Is there a reference to see about a relevant theorem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem

Comment: @copper.hat I can't see a statement about global existence/

Comment: You need to look up a formal statement of the Picard Lindelöf theorem, Wikipedia is not the best reference. Then note that the conditions imply a global solution.